# jQuery How to make a popup Appears / Disappears on timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When my website loads, the popup appears - I need to make it automatically close after a specific time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //select the POPUP FRAME and show it

    $("#popup").hide().fadeIn(1000);

    //close the POPUP if the button with id="close" is clicked
    $("#close").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#popup").fadeOut(1000);
    });

});
```

There is already a button but i need to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) function for that:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#popup").hide().fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);

  $("#close").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#popup").fadeOut(1000);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup">popup</div>
```

Please mind the note that is given on the documentation:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript have option **setTimeout** .setTimeout is a native JavaScript function (although it can be used with a library such as jQuery, as we’ll see later on), which calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay (in milliseconds).

```
setTimeout(function() {
      $("#popup").fadeOut(1000);
 }, 1000);
```

or in jquery use [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/). Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

```
$("#popup").delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
```